# orthogonal group in characteristic 2

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields, quadratic-forms, orthogonal-matrices

Let $O(2,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ be the orthogonal group of order two matrices. On $\mathbb{Z}_2$ there should exist just one odd quadratic form, hence the stabilizer subgroup $O^-$ of an odd quadratic for should be the whole group. Is it really so or I am confused? On the other hand the even stabilizer $O^+$ should have index 3, so - since the order of $O$ is 6 - I guess $O^+$ is just $\pm Id$. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: I think you are trying to represent quadratic forms by (symmetric) matrices. This doesn't work in characteristic 2.

Comment: no, I am sorry, I should have explained. By even and odd I mean the Arf invariant of a quadratic form on a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-vector space. I will correct the question.

Comment: @IMeasy: You should also make your notation $\mathbb{Z}_2$ clear, since it can mean two things.   Is this what the tag 'finite-fields' is for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that, by $\mathbb{Z}_2$, you mean the finite field of order $2$, then 
$$ O_2^{\pm}(q) \cong D_{2(q\mp 1)}$$
where $D_{2(q\mp 1)}$ is the dihedral group of order $2(q\mp 1)$. Taking $q=2$, one obtains that $O_2^+(2)$ is cyclic of order $2$ (although not equal to $\pm I$ you suggest, because $-I=I$), while $O_2^-(2)$ is dihedral of order $6$.

One can calculate all this directly, or you can refer to Proposition 2.9.1 of Kleidman and Liebeck's book.

Comment: Yes I meant the finite field of order 2, thank you! What is the precise book reference that you suggest?

Comment: *The subgroup structure of the finite classical groups* by Kleidman and Liebeck. I have an e-copy and will send it to you if you want (my e-mail is on my user page).

Comment: [Kleidman and Liebeck - The subgroup structure of the finite classical groups](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511629235).